# How C# protected access modifier when applied to a member variable works

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have 2 classes, Base and child class.
Base class has a protected int variable. My understanding is that any protected member of a class can only be accessed in a child class, It cannot be accessed from say creating an Instance of a class and accessing the protected member. How is this working then?

```
  class BaseClass
        {
            protected int x = 0;

            private static void Funny(BaseClass c, ChildClass d)
            {
                d.x = 9; // How can we access x here? 
                c.x = 0; // How can we access x here?
            }
        }

        class ChildClass: BaseClass
        {
            public void MyFunc()
            {
                x = 0; // This should be OK, because x is a protected member of 
            }

            private static void Funny(BaseClass c,ChildClass d)
            {

                d.x = 9;
                c.x=0;// This is giving compile time error? According to me even above line should give compile time error


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the scope of access modifiers is the **class**, not the **instance**. This means that a private member can be accessed within the class on any instance.

```
public class Price
{
    private int amount;

    private static void CheckAmountOf(Price price)
    {
        // The following line is possible, even if `amount` is private and we are accessing an
        // instance of the object which was passed by a parameter.
        if (price.amount < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidValueException("The price cannot be negative.");
        }
    }
}
```

This, by the way, makes it possible (and easy) to [override Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Otherwise, you would be limited to public properties only, which may not be exactly what you want.

```
class Price
{
    private int amount;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        ...
        var price = obj as Price;
        ...
        // The next line is valid, even if `amount` is private and even if the initial argument
        // was of type `object`. This way, you don't need to have a corresponding `Amount`
        // property with a public getter.
        return this.amount == price.amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that!

Comment: This answer doesn't actually explain why the final `c.x=0` doesn't work, does it?

Answer (score 1):

MainMa's answer explains why most of the accesses work. However, to understand why the final one doesn't work, let's see what we could do if it was allowed:

```
class SiblingClass: BaseClass
{
}

    //...And then, inside some other code:
    var sibling = new SiblingClass();
    var child = new ChildClass();
    ChildClass.Funny(sibling, child);
```

(This also requires `ChildClass.Funny` to be made public)

This would all compile- sibling inherits from `BaseClass` so it could be passed in for a parameter of type `BaseClass`. But now a `ChildClass` can access a member on a `SiblingClass`. That's not what we expect from the `protected` keyword- we expect that to give access only to things it inherits from its parent, not to *all* other classes which also inherit from its parent.

So to prevent this unexpected access happening, it's made illegal.